# oracle two different session

Tags: oracle, session, locking

in our work we create two  .net listener,
 first one:
 calling oracle stored procedure that insert bulk of data into table(table1) using insert into select syntax:
insert into table1 select c1,c2... from tbl2 inner join tbl3....
then we use explicity commit;

second listener:
calling oracle procedure that reading data inserted into table1 via listener1

but we notice that even the record inserted into table1 listener2 couldn't see that recordat same time even that commit is use.

my question is how does cmmit work when we use insert ...select?
is this issue related to session?when listener 1 session end listener 2 can read data?

please help,

thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong terms...

A listener is a server application that listens to the incoming client requests and hands it to the DB engine. A listener is not being used on the client end.

A session is not related to the data you can see, a transaction is the object that controls that.

Oracle works in a very clear way - After a transaction has committed - all the new transactions can see it, and already existing transactions can see the new content based on it transaction configurations..
I recommend you reading about isolation levels in that context 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.isolationlevel(v=vs.110).aspx

By default - the moment (and in DB it is defined by SCN) a transaction have been committed - the data is visible to the client.

Bottom line - your issue is related either to transaction isolation levels (in the case the reading transaction started before the commit), or to the writer, which does not commit the data when you think it is (a transaction issue).
After the call to transaction.Commit() in .net returned - the data is already visible, and other transactions are seeing it.

You're second question was how commit works.
This is a very complicated process in Oracle, so I'll give a really short description: 
 1. When you commit, Oracle first runs some verifications before the commit itself (for example, runs the deferred constraints).
 2. After oracle knows it can safely commit the changes it gets the system time (SCN) , write the commit itself to the redo log, and flushes the data to disk (for consistency).
 3. Sends an ACK to the user, that the data is already visible to the world.
 4. marks the buffers been used as free.

---

Something I want to add, just to make sure (and I'm writing it half a sleep - so excuse me if it does not compile...)
In you're .net code - your code should be logically equivalent to it:

```
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connStr);
con.Open();

OracleTransaction trans = con.BeginTransaction();

OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.Connection = cmd;
cmd.CommandText = "insert into ...";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Dispose();

trans.Commit();
trans.Dispose();

con.Close();
con.Dispose();
```

and if you're using LINQ - make sure you create the transaction scope on the right area.